# Parsing multiple line output into single cell within CSV file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

This is my code.

```
#!/bin/bash

for domain in google.com twitter.com
do
        ns_record=$(dig NS +short $domain)
        echo "$domain" "," "$ns_record" >> output.csv
done
```

**It generates an output which is mentioned in below pic.**

[image]

**I want output in the below format.**

[image]

**What should be my code?**

Answer (score 2):

You can save the `ns_record` output as an array and then loop over the array outputting at a column position of your choosing. You will have to make a special case for the first record output at the end of `$domain`, but that is all simple to do with `printf`.

For example, you can modify your script to do:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -i col2pos=20     ## set column 2 position

for domain in google.com twitter.com; do
  ns_record=($(dig NS +short $domain))    ## create array of dig output
  
  nsspaces=$(( col2pos - ${#domain} ))    ## get no. of chars in domain
  
  ## output domain followd by nsspaces spaces and first element of ns_record
  printf "%s%*s%s\n" "$domain" "$nsspaces" " " "${ns_record[0]}"
  
  ## loop outputting remaining ns_record at col2pos
  for ((i=1; i< ${#ns_record[@]}; i++)); do
    printf "%*s%s\n" "$col2pos" " " "${ns_record[i]}"
  done
  
done
```

(you can set `$col2pos` as you like)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash ns_record.sh
google.com          ns2.google.com.
                    ns1.google.com.
                    ns3.google.com.
                    ns4.google.com.
twitter.com         a.r06.twtrdns.net.
                    d.r06.twtrdns.net.
                    ns4.p34.dynect.net.
                    ns1.p34.dynect.net.
                    d01-01.ns.twtrdns.net.
                    c.r06.twtrdns.net.
                    d01-02.ns.twtrdns.net.
                    b.r06.twtrdns.net.
                    ns2.p34.dynect.net.
                    ns3.p34.dynect.net.
```

---

**Sorted `ns_record`**

You may want the output of the `ns_record` information to appear sorted. You can easily do that piping the output of `dig` to `sort`, e.g.

```bash
  ns_record=($(dig NS +short $domain | sort)) ## create array and sort
```

**Sorted Output**

Now your output appears as:

```
$ bash ns_record.sh
google.com          ns1.google.com.
                    ns2.google.com.
                    ns3.google.com.
                    ns4.google.com.
twitter.com         a.r06.twtrdns.net.
                    b.r06.twtrdns.net.
                    c.r06.twtrdns.net.
                    d.r06.twtrdns.net.
                    d01-01.ns.twtrdns.net.
                    d01-02.ns.twtrdns.net.
                    ns1.p34.dynect.net.
                    ns2.p34.dynect.net.
                    ns3.p34.dynect.net.
                    ns4.p34.dynect.net.
```

I find that a bit easier to look through.

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: This is a Good solution. Just one question, the `dig` command is it a default *NIX utility? I am yet to check it but never used it honestly, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes, it is a Linux utility (DNS Information Groper), but there is no reason it can't be ported to run on the dark-side. I just suspect that windows `net ...` has a similar utility. (never had any reason to look over there, always had Nix at the fingertips `:)`

Comment: Excellent, well explained answer

Comment: Every once in a while I get one right `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` with formatted `printf` output:

```
#!/bin/bash

for domain in google.com twitter.com ; do
    col1="$domain"
    for col2 in $(dig NS +short "$domain") ; do
        printf '%-15s %s\n' "$col1" "$col2"
        col1=" "
    done
done
```

```
google.com      ns1.google.com.
                ns3.google.com.
                ns4.google.com.
                ns2.google.com.
twitter.com     b.r06.twtrdns.net.
                d01-01.ns.twtrdns.net.
                d.r06.twtrdns.net.
                d01-02.ns.twtrdns.net.
                ns2.p34.dynect.net.
                ns1.p34.dynect.net.
                a.r06.twtrdns.net.
                c.r06.twtrdns.net.
                ns4.p34.dynect.net.
                ns3.p34.dynect.net.
```